# How to get datas by month? Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

Using the `created_at` column, I want to **retrieve data(s) in one query**:

- from past year
- group by month

---

Expected returned values should:

```
$data: [
    1 : [
        //datas for january
    ],

    2 : [
        //datas for february
    ],

    //etc.
]
```

---

I tried this query:

```
$data = User::query()
    ->whereYear('created_at', now()->year - 1)
    ->get(function ($q){
        return groupBy(function ($q){
            return Carbon::parse($q->created_at)->format('m');
        });
    });
```

But I receive this error:

> stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Can someone could help me the proper querying for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested closure functions with same variable names are very confusing, you can simplify things here

Call the `groupBy` method on the collection after `get` instead of the builder which only accepts a column name apparently

```php
$data = User::query()
            ->whereYear('created_at', now()->year - 1)
            ->get()
            ->groupBy(function ($q) {
                return Carbon::parse($q->created_at)->format('m');
            });
```

See [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-groupby)

Comment: thanks man. I thought it needs a subquery. you just nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

you should use sql method **MONTH()**  to extract month from date then use groubby .like this :

```
 User::query()->select('created_at',  DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) month'))
->whereYear('created_at', now()->subYear())
->groupby('month')
->get();
```

Comment: This produces a syntax error `select *, MONTH(created_at) month from `users` where year(`created_at`) = ? group by `month``

Comment: it returns unique values. I just want to group the datas by month in the last year. Thanks for the response Sir.

Comment: there should be two datas in month january but here displays only one data. Take a look on my **expected values** on my post. Thanks for the response Sir.